# Django: How to query two models with relationship to each other while keeping the relationship to the parent model?

Tags: python, django

I have a parent model which is `Profile` and two other models which is `Courses` and `Course_student`.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

...
first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('First Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, )
middle_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Middle Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
...


class Courses(models.Model):
YESNO = (
    ('Yes', 'Yes'),
    ('No', 'No'),
)

profile                     = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name='course_profile', verbose_name=_('Profile'))
course_taken                = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Course'), max_length=255)
name_of_school              = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name of School'), max_length=255)
school_location             = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('School Location'), max_length=255)
period_of_attendance_from   = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Period of Attendance (From)'), max_length=255)
period_of_attendance_to     = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Period of Attendance (To)'), max_length=255)
nr_students                 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Total Number of Students'), null=True, blank=True)
created_on                  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_on                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Course')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Course')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.course_taken)


class Course_student(models.Model):
YESNO = (
    ('Yes', 'Yes'),
    ('No', 'No'),
)

course = models.ForeignKey('Courses', related_name='course_student_details', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('Course'), blank=True, null=True)
profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', related_name='course_student_profile', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('Profile'), blank=True, null=True)
standing = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Standing'), null=True, blank=True)
grade = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Grade'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
completed = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Completed'), choices=YESNO, max_length=255)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Student Details')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Student Details')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.course)
```

`admin.py`

```
class CourseUploaderInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CourseUploader
    extra = 1

class CourseStudentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Course_student
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Courses)
class CoursesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     inlines = [Course_studentInline, CorseUploaderInline,]
```

`Course_student` has `Foreignkey` to `Courses` and `Profile`

- As you can see, `Course_student` has fields for `profile`, `standing`, `grade` and `completed`, this will hold the details of the student for a particular course and particular profile/student.
  while `Courses` has `M2M` to `Profile` so that I can tag the student what courses she/he have.
  `Profile` will hold the basic information of the student

What I am trying to do is, combine the `Courses` and `Course_student` by filtering using the `Profile` such as:

`view.py`

```
def profile(request, pk):
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(profile=pk)
    course = Course.objects.filter(profile=pk) # I tried here the select_related()
```

P.S. I am new to Django and Python, I hope you'll be easy on me :) TIA
Suggestion is also welcome on what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime troubleshooting my queryset using the `select_related()`, I found out that the problem is on my template syntax that displays' the combine `course` and `course_student` list

I was using the syntax `{{ course.name_of_school }}` instead of `{{ course.course.name_of_school }}` in my template.
Using the `select_related()` is the correct way to follow the reverse relationship. I just missed the syntax on the template.

`course = Course_student.objects.select_related('course').filter(profile=pk)`

Finally, I can sleep now.